# Trouble with using split

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to split text read from a file, and when I do it takes in the whole line as an array element, am I doing this wrong or is just that a split is not what I need to use.

```
public void readBoard(String file)throws FileNotFoundException
{
    File clboard = new File ("myBoard.csv");
    Scanner x = new Scanner(clboard);
    while(x.hasNext())
    {
        String c = x.nextLine();
        String [] myboard =c.split(",,");
        int p1= Integer.parseInt(myboard[1]);
        int p2= Integer.parseInt(myboard[2]); 
        if(myboard[0].equals("Chute"))
        {
            board[p1][p2]= new Chute();
        }
        else
        {
            board[p1][p2]= new Ladder();
        }
    }   
}
```

and here is the file I am reading

```
29
Chute,1,0
Chute,2,0
Chute,3,0
Chute,4,0
Chute,5,0
Chute,6,0
Chute,7,0
Chute,8,0
Chute,9,0
Chute,0,1
Chute,0,2
Chute,0,3
Chute,9,1
Chute,9,2
Chute,9,3
Ladder,0,5
Ladder,1,5
Ladder,2,5
Ladder,3,5
Ladder,4,5
Ladder,5,5
Ladder,6,5
Ladder,7,5
Ladder,8,5
Ladder,9,5
Ladder,9,6
Ladder,9,7
Ladder,9,8
Ladder,9,9
```

Comment: Please read the relevant documentation before posting a question: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Comment: Like Matt said, please RTM before posting a question. You can also take help of Javadoc popup support found in Eclipse and other IDEs to make it easier for you.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using single comma you are using double comma in split method.

```
String [] myboard =c.split(",,");
```

Above line should be:

```
String [] myboard =c.split(",");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are splitting with the wrong delimiter. A delimiter is just totally matched inside the string that needs to be split.

```
String [] myboard =c.split(",,");
```

this would work for strings like `"Ladder,,8,,8"`. What you need is

```
String [] myboard =c.split(",");
```

Answer (score 1):

String [] myboard =c.split(",,");
would look for the String ,, and spilt there.

what you wnat is String [] myboard =c.split(",");

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is the two commas

```
String [] myboard =c.split(",,");
```

It needs to be

```
String [] myboard =c.split(",");
```

i.e. you want to split the `String` on a single comma not two in a row.

Answer (score 1):

```
String [] myboard =c.split(",");
```

That should work. Split will cut the string at each comma it finds, so you'll get three pieces.